# Show different menu and items to different users

Tags: drupal, drop-down-menu, categories

I am making drupal website for students on which they will be able to upload and download documents for exams. When the user registers he will be able to choose his university and type of files that he is interested at.

My question is: How can I set up that every user can see only the documents from his university?

Answer (score 0):

This module do exactly what you need : [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

The module provides hight granularity configuration for node access permissions

Comment: Thanks for your replay. One more question. When student is registered he can select what classes he is going to (5 classes every semester). How can I set up that first menu item on drop list shows that 5 classes that he selected?

Comment: Check this thread : [How do I add an access condition to a menu item](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/116/how-do-i-add-an-access-condition-to-a-menu-item)